# How to resolve the "functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code126"

Tags: javascript, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore, eslint

I am getting the error below:

> === Deploying to 'nompu-website'...
>
> i  deploying functions
>   Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
>
> functions@ lint /home/superlelo/Desktop/publishToday/functions
>   eslint .
>
> sh: 1: eslint: Permission denied
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 126
>   npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 126
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /home/superlelo/.npm/_logs/2019-09-24T15_05_43_357Z-debug.log
>
> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code126

When I run the command: `firebase deploy --only functions`. I get the same error when I am with or without admin privileges.

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "build":"npm run build",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here is the complete log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   '/home/superlelo/Desktop/publishToday/functions',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'lint' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelint', 'lint', 'postlint' ]
5 info lifecycle functions@~prelint: functions@
6 info lifecycle functions@~lint: functions@
7 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/superlelo/Desktop/publishToday/functions/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/sbin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/superlelo/bin:/usr/bin/java/bin:/home/superlelo/Android/sdk/emulator:/home/superlelo/Android/sdk/tools:/home/superlelo/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/home/superlelo/Android/sdk/platform-tools
9 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: CWD: /home/superlelo/Desktop/publishToday/functions
10 silly lifecycle functions@~lint: Args: [ '-c', 'eslint .' ]
11 silly lifecycle functions@~lint: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
12 info lifecycle functions@~lint: Failed to exec lint script
13 verbose stack Error: functions@ lint: `eslint .`
13 verbose stack Exit status 126
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid functions@
15 verbose cwd /home/superlelo/Desktop/publishToday
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-64-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "--prefix" "/home/superlelo/Desktop/publishToday/functions" "run" "lint"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 126
22 error functions@ lint: `eslint .`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the functions@ lint script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
```

Can anyone suggest how can I resolve this? I am using npm 6.9.0 on a linux Ubuntu bionic beaver.

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the debug log file that it said it created for you?

Comment: @DougStevenson: I have added the log file - I am still trying to understand it